# Set non-injected parameters when importing objects using MEF

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dependency-injection, mef

I have the following scenario in my Silverlight 4 application:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    [Import()]
    public TheChild Child { get; set; }
}

[Export()]
public class TheChild
{
    [ImportingConstructor()]
    public TheChild(String myName, IAmTheService service) { ... }
}

[Export(typeof(IAmTheService))]
public class TheService : IAmTheService
{
    public void DoSomething(String theName);
}
```

As you can see, TheChild's constructor requires one imported parameter and one static value that is context-sensitive (has to be provided by the parent). The string value cannot come from AppSettings, configuration, etc. and can only be provided by the current instance of the parent class (TheViewModel in this case).

As a rule-of-thumb, I've always approached dependency-injection as follows:

1. Required dependencies are satisfied through constructor injection
2. Optional dependencies are satisfied through property injection

The "myName" parameter is required so I would prefer to set it through the constructor but given the way MEF works, I realize this may have to change.

Can you tell me how you've handled this scenario and your thoughts behind the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a specific import contract in conjunction with `[ImportingConstructor]`.  For example:

```
[Export()]
public class TheChild
{
    [ImportingConstructor()]
    public TheChild([Import("MyName")] String myName, IAmTheService service) { ... }
```

Given that, an export of a string decorated with `[Export("MyName")]` will be required and used to fulfill the dependency.  Any of the `[Import]` specifications should work in this case (ie: importing a subclass by type, importing by name, etc).

Comment: There is no export corresponding to "myName" and since it's utilization is only in this one place with no possibility of replacement (via modularity or extension), defining an export seems like overkill.

Comment: Plus, I'd have to define an export for every ViewModel in my application (that consumes TheChild). Not very practical.

Comment: @SonOfPirate You only need a single export, if you export by name.  But this would provide a mechanism to handle it.  That being said, if there's no possibility of replacement, why not just set it via a property afterwards?

Comment: It needs a single export PER VALUE. As I said, this class will be used by many parents, each providing a different value.

Comment: My issue with setting a property afterwards is that it makes the value optional as calling code could "forget" to provide the value. As I said in the original post, our policy is to inject required values through the constructor. This ensures that the value is provided.